# Need to change state of widget from another place not widget itself

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I have 2 instances of the same widget(w1 and w2) with a button and an onPressed function. I know to disable the onPress by setting that up with a null value, so far so good. The issue in hand is to solve how to disable w2 onPress when clicking w1 once and enable it again if it is clicked once again.

Even though I send a variable containing if widget has been pressed, disabling never happens  because I can not trigger from outside(Widget containing my 2 instances) the setState of each widget separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of solutions. You could use a more sophisticated state management system (such as Provider or Bloc), but it might be simpler to instead try "lifting state".

"Lifting state" refers to pulling state out of the children and moving it to the parent.

Instead of having the children be stateful, they can become stateless, and the widget that contains them will be made stateful, and will keep track of which buttons are enabled and which are not.

```dart
// example button, actual implementation may be different
class MyButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback? onPressed;
  final String text;

  const MyButton({Key? key, this.onPressed, required this.text,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: onPressed,
    child: Text(text),
  );
}

class ButtonContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  // boilerplate
}

class ButtonContainerState extends State<ButtonContainer> {
  bool isSecondButtonEnabled = true;

  void toggleSecondButton() => setState(() => isSecondButtonEnabled = !isSecondButtonEnabled);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Row(
    children: [
      MyButton(
        text: "Button 1",
        onPressed: toggleSecondButton,
      ),
      MyButton(
        text: "Button 2",
        onPressed: isSecondButtonEnabled ? someOtherFunction : null,
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  It point me in the right direction. Something else that should be taken into account is that initState is only called once when building the widget and not each time state has changed.  This was ultimately was happening to me, state was not being refreshed since  I was assuming each time would  go through initState and setting up the variables value. Cheers!